# How to Send the document from react native DocumentPicker response to a web api as byte[]

Tags: react-native, document, react-native-web

I am using the react-native-document-picker form choosing the file from the Android mobile using the following code

```
DocumentPicker.show({
  filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()],
},(error,res) => {
  // Android
  console.log(
     res.uri,
     res.type, // mime type
     res.fileName,
     res.fileSize
  );
});
```

and the output of the above log is like

```
uri: 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A48',
type: 'image/jpeg'
fileName: 'TestImage.jpeg'
fileSize: 5301
```

How do i get the Byte array of the uploaded file in react native and send it as an input to web api post request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me

```js
    DocumentPicker.show({
      filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()],
    },(error,res) => {
 
  
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('name', 'testName'); // you can append anyone.
        data.append('photo', {
          uri: res.uri,
          type: res.type,
          name: res.fileName,
        });

        fetch('http://ApiUrl/api/Controller/UploadFile', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
          body: data
        }).then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
            throw error;
          });
});
```

Comment: How can I select song file?

Comment: it will be the same way, provide the right format and file name

Comment: You don't need to set `Content-Type` header manually. https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/505#issuecomment-293064470