# How do I upload files from mobile to the API in React Native?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, axios, apache-commons-fileupload

The react native app (Android in this case) is supposed to upload files selected using the *react-native-document-picker* and POST it to the backend api. The backend is a Spring Boot app and uses Apache Commons Fileupload and therefore `multipart=false`. Now in Angular, I am able to append the files to a formData, which would be passed in the request body where as other "@RequestParams" would be sent via HttpParams.

I tried the similar approach but didn't work, not sure what I am missing. The following solutions also didn't help:

- [File upload in React Native through fetch, XHR and axios fails on Android but works on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62815251/file-upload-in-react-native-through-fetch-xhr-and-axios-fails-on-android-but-wo)
- [How to Send the document from react native DocumentPicker response to a web api as byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690047/how-to-send-the-document-from-react-native-documentpicker-response-to-a-web-api)

**Note:** I cannot modify the backend api to enable multipart. Axio is used for api calls

This is what I have right now:

**UploadButton**
import { uploadDocuments } from '../../services/ApiService';

```
const result = await DocumentPicker.pick({
   type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles]
});

const uploadData = {
    parentId: 1,
    userId: 1
}

const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", files[0]);

uploadFiles(data, uploadData).then(res => {
   console.log('files uploaded');
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log('errr uploading files: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
})
```

**uploadFiles - API Service**

```
return axios.post(`${API_URL}/api/uploadFiles`, formData, {
        params: {
            parentId: parentId,
            userId: userId
        }, 
        responseType: 'text', 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    });
```

**Spring Boot API**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE})
  public ResponseEntity<String> addDocuments(@RequestParam Long parentId,
                                             @RequestParam Long userId,
                                             HttpServletRequest request) {
//
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setRepository(new File(UPLOAD_DIR));

    factory.setSizeThreshold(DiskFileItemFactory.DEFAULT_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
    factory.setFileCleaningTracker(null);

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
// rest of the code
}
```

**Logs - All I get is 400 Bad Request - No errors in backend**

```
 LOG  uploading files: 1
 LOG  file data => name: sample.pdf uri: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Asample.pdf
 LOG  dots: [{"guid":"170560870473535714196193642705","displayName":"sample.pdf"}]
 LOG  errr uploading files: {"message":"Request failed with status code 400","name":"AxiosError","stack":"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400\n    at settle (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&lazy=true&minify=false&app=com.dvsapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:174577:37)\n    at onloadend (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle//&platform=android&dev=true&lazy=true&minify=false&app=com.dv***Trimmed to clear spam filter***,"config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"adapter":["xhr","http"],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"multipart/form-data","Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ},"params":{"parentId":2,"userId":22,"responseType":"text","method":"post","url":"https://apigone.virtual-datarooms.uk/api/buploadFiles","data":{"_parts":[["file",{"fileCopyUri":null,"size":861148,"name":"sample.pdf","type":"application/pdf","uri":"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Asample.pdf"}]]}},"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST","status":400}
```